# How to Fit WPF StackPanel to Grid Cell

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, stackpanel

I have a StackPanel control in my WPF project, and it is in column 0 row 2 of a Grid. How can I autofit the StackPanel size to the size of that grid cell? Setting the StackPanel width and height to "auto" will just size it to its contents. I could explicitly set its width and height to numerical values, but I was wondering if there was a cleaner, more accurate way. Thank you.

Relevant XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="74*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="74*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="421*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Content="{StaticResource LoginWindow_Title}" Style="{StaticResource TitleH1}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <Label Content="{StaticResource LoginWindow_Subtitle}" Style="{StaticResource TitleH2}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Label Content="Log in"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Post the relevant XAML.

Comment: Use `DockPanel` instead

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `StackPanel` is not in `Grid`, it`s inside `Border`. So for it to take all available space you can set horizontal and vertical alignment to `Stretch` both for it and its parent `Border`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="74*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="74*"/>
       <RowDefinition Height="421*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
            BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"  Grid.Row="2">
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Label Content="Log in"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Even so, like others mentioned, some other panel almost definetely will be better in this case.

Comment: I actually forgot it had a border until I posted the XAML code... thanks for your answer! I'm confused at the remarks that another panel would be better. Doesn't that depend on what I want to do with the content _inside_ the panel (which I didn't disclose any information about in the question)?

Comment: Yes, you are right, that depends on content and what you want to do with it. Indeed, you didn\`t disclose any info about content so we jumped to conclusions, I suppose =)

Answer (score 8):

The answer is always the same... *don't use a `StackPanel` for layout purposes*. They are primarily used to arrange UI elements that are very unlikely to change size. Even if you resized the `StackPanel` to the correct size, it would not help because a `StackPanel` does *not* rearrange or resize it's content items. If you want this functionality, you'll have to use one of the other `Panel` controls like a `Grid` instead.

Answer (score 1):

<Grid>
  <Border>
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" ...